# Website hosting service problem with loading

Tags: web, hosting

I have a website that I have hosted for a while now... It seemed to work fine, but now it just shows a blank page when I visit it.
Could this be a hosting error? If not what else?

Answer (score 0):

Your question really needs more details for anyone to be able to give you any help.
I this page just a static HTML file, or is it a database-driven site (WordPress or Drupal for example).
Have you checked the error logs for your hosting provider and have you tried contacting your hosting provider to see what they say.